# How to restore plymouth to its original state?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, plymouth

When I first installed 12.04 plymouth would sometimes show a few commands beneath the ubuntu logo. I later learned that it conflicts with proprietary drivers.I tried to fix this using the Plymouth Manager but that only made it worse. Then I followed the instructions in this post "http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-fix-the-plymouth-boot-screen-when-using-proprietary-graphics-drivers/" and now plymouth doesn't show up at all. All I see is commands flushing down a terminal then ubuntu loads. Is there a way I could get plymouth back to its original state? Like a purge and reinstall without damaging my system or getting things too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restore plymouth I had to install Super Boot Loader and install the proprietary driver fix the program offered and then undo the fix (applying and undoing the fix are automated actions that can be done with the click of a button). After that I installed boor-repair and it provided a fresh installation of grub2. With grub restored to its original state, plymouth was fixed.